# Call Statements return Different result

Tags: python-3.x, types, pytorch

In Python programming, which using Pytorch i got this error

> 4 and >5 are printing the type of x to check the type of tensor, but returning different results

why does this happen?[My Code of Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sFeX.jpg)

```
x = x.type(torch.int64)
print(x.type())
type(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known behavior](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-0_4_0-migration-guide/#the-type-of-a-tensor-has-changed) of PyTorch since version 0.4, though the maintainers don't offer a justification.

> Note also that the `type()` of a Tensor no longer reflects the data type. Use `isinstance()` or `x.type()` instead
>
> ```
> x = torch.DoubleTensor([1, 1, 1])
> print(type(x))  # was torch.DoubleTensor
> # "<class 'torch.Tensor'>"
> print(x.type())  # OK: 'torch.DoubleTensor'
> # 'torch.DoubleTensor'
> print(isinstance(x, torch.DoubleTensor))  # OK: True
> # True
> ```